# How is this Patch Panel even working

Tags: cabling, patch-panel

I recently took a Jr. Developer position at a small company. I've been asked to solve a network issue at one of our remote warehouses (I'm the interim IT / Network guy). I did a little bit of Panduit work in VoTech in highschool however I'm a little lost with what I've found.

[image]

In the above image all of the cables patched into this panel are only using the blue / white blue wires...

Somehow the connection actually works however it is spotty constantly drops and cannot handle any real load for some reason. It's causing our time clocks to experience issues, and I'm incredibly tired of hearing about it at this point.

A weird thing I've noticed is that all of these cables are not in the blue position on the panel... wtf??

What would be the purpose of doing it like this, how is the functioning, and should / can I redo this without affecting things terribly?

I really just want to know why it would be done this way and what benefits this provides? When I connected a cable tester from the connection at the time clock to the cable that is referenced by the errors it threw a fault on 4&5 pair but no lights on the others (obviously they aren't connected).

[image: Picture of the cable in question connecting into an RJ45 patch panel]

Comment: We have no way to know how your network works. Is it even ethernet? What's on each end of each leg? What protocols are being used? Is this a one-way (unidirectional) system? You really need to ask the person(s) who designed it. (At first glance, it looks like phone wiring.)

Comment: It is RJ45 connections on either side

Comment: Adding another image to provide more clarity

Comment: Just because it is an 8P8C connector doesn't make it ethernet. Even 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX require two pairs, and 1000BASE-T requires four pairs. It looks more like some type of voice or serial connection. We simply do not have enough information to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the top panel is going to a local PBX (either analog or propietary digital) for voice services which only use a single pair each. I don't think it has anything to do with your Ethernet network other than sharing the structured cabling infrastructure.

Comment: Yeah the more I look at it I feel like this is correct, apologies for wasting time.